# HTML vertical alignment not working

Tags: html

I am not a web developer, nor do I have any training making websites, but i am responsible for updating our company website. I am trying to add some PDF documents for our clients to read.

I am putting the documents in rows of three with images as links but for some reasons the ones on the right hand side are a little higher than the others in the row.

I tried using vertical align but it didn't do anything. Maybe I am trying it in the wrong spot. Can anyone take a look at the code and tell me what I am doing wrong? Aside from everything . . .

Here is the site link:
http://nunainnovations.com/media-literature

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The other images in the row are wrapped in `<p>`/`</p>` tags, which adds a bit of margin above and below them.  The rightmost images are not, hence they appear a bit higher.

Answer (score 0):

The code structure tells the problem. You wrap your other PDFs in a `<P>` tag but miss the first one in very row. I would try to ADD a `<p>` tag for every first PDF element like this:

`<p><a href="http://nunainnovations.com/files/files/CCarticle.pdf" title="North of 60 Article" style="border: 0px dashed lime;"><img src="http://nunainnovations.com/files/images/CCArticle.jpg" align="right" style="float:right" alt="CC Article"></a></p>`

this will solve your problem in an easy way.